# How to assign an IP to a seleniumGrid

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I need seleniumGrid to be accessible via localhost (127.0.0.1) and instead of that, it is being offered in address:port  192.168.1.39:4444

What command option can I use to make it use localhost?
The command I'm using, right now is:

`java -jar  selenium-server-4.2.2.jar  standalone`

I'm using MacOS, 12.5 (Monterey)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *host* flag:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-4.2.2.jar -host 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: It looks like selenium-server-standalone-4.2.2.jar is not available anymore
Do you know how to get it?

Comment: If the official Selenium site doesn't provide this file, there was probably a big reason to stop the release. I would use the most recent version or open an issue on Selenium's GitHub repo. Either way, this is not related to the question itself. If you find the answer satisfactory, I would suggest marking it as Answered, to signal that this answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to download a copy of selenium-server-standalone-4.2.2.jar and it allows to assign the IP and port for the server.